# mysql query trouble

Tags: mysql

in my database i have phone numbers with country code , which look somthing like

```
0044-123456
0044-123456
0014-123456
0014-123456
0024-123456
0024-123456
0034-123456
0044-123456
0044-123456
0024-123456
0034-123456
084-123456
084-123456
```

i want to total up the numbers by country, something like this output

```
0044 (2)
0024 (2)
0034 (1)
084 (2)
064 (5)
```

Is it possible to do this with a SQL query?

Comment: So you just want to extract the part before the dash? I'm not sure, if I understood you correctly. Furthermore this is not a typical candidate for community wiki.

Comment: ok i will not connect to wiki here after, i applogoies..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this one a try:

```
SELECT count(SUBSTR(phoneNumber, 1, LOCATE("-", phoneNumber)))
FROM tableName
GROUP BY SUBSTR(phoneNumber, 1, LOCATE("-", phoneNumber));
```

Comment: Grouping by phoneNumber wouldn't work, since it would count unique numbers, not unique country codes.

Comment: You're right. But the alternative should do it. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
  SELECT phoneNumber,
         SUBSTR(phoneNumber, 1, LOCATE("-", phoneNumber) - 1) AS countryCode,
         COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM phoneNumbers
GROUP BY countryCode
```

i.e. extract the country code from the number, and group on it.